# Удаление повторяющихся элементов в массиве со смещением java

Tags: java, массивы

Есть следующий метод: при наличии повторяющихся элементов в массиве остаются только первые вхождения этих элементов. То есть повторный элемент исключается из массива путем смещения всех следующих за ним элементов влево (на 1 позицию), а последнему элементу присваивается значение, равное нулю.
Есть такой код:

```
public static int[] delete(int[] inp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < inp.length; j++) {
            if (inp[i] == inp[j]) {
                for (int k = j; k < inp.length - 1; k++) {
                    inp[k] = inp[k + 1];
                }
                inp[inp.length - 1] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Метод работает, если повторяющихся элементов не более двух. Для массива типа [1,1,1,2] результат уже некорректный: [1,1,2,0].

Подскажите, где могут быть ошибки и недоработки в коде?

Comment: В итоге нужно из  [1,1,1,2]  получить [1,2,0,0] ?

Comment: После того как произошло смещение надо сделать j--. Потому что элемент сместился и вы его пропускаете. Чтобы этого не было отнимайте от j единицу и все будет в порядке

Comment: @VladVetrov да, именно так.

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко а где это смещение сделать, чтобы не поймать ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, не подскажете? Элементы у меня смещаются в цикле с k = j, потом обнуляется последний элемент в массиве

Comment: @user249023 Да. Вот после этого цикла с k, нужно написать j--. А ещё у вас обнуляется всегда только последний элемент в массиве. Можно, например, хранить число n - условную длину массива. И после каждого сдвига отнимать 1. Тогда будет и понятно, что обнулять нужно [n-1]ый элемент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подряд идущие повторы удаляются одним смещением

```
    int[] a = {1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 5, 8};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // посмотреть оригинальный массив

    int k = 0;                               // счётчик удаляемых элементов
    int n = a.length;                        // размер массива исключая нулевой хвост
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < i && a[j] != a[i]) j++;   // а не является ли i-ый элемент дублем?
        if (j < i) {                         // если является
            k++;                             // то увеличить счётчик удаления
        } else if (k > 0) {                  // иначе при необходимости (есть что удалять:)
            i = i - k;                       // вернуться на k элементов назад
            n = n - k;                       // рассчитать новый размер
            System.out.println("удаление с " + i + " по " + (i + k - 1) + " вкл. (" + k +"шт.)");
            for (j = i; j < n; j++) {        // сместить элементы, затирая удаляемые
                a[j] = a[j + k];
            }
            k = 0;                           // сбросить счётчик удаления
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));  // посмотреть промежуточный итог
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (k > 0) {    // если последний элемент оказался дублем, 
        i = i - k;  // то обработка продолжается и после выхода из цикла 
        n = n - k;  // но точно такая же как в цикле
        System.out.println("удаление с " + i + " по " + (i + k - 1) + " вкл. (" + k +"шт.)");
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {        // сместить элементы
            a[j] = a[j + k];
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));  // посмотреть промежуточный итог
    }

    System.out.println("замена на нули с " + n + " (" + (a.length - n) +"шт.)");
    for (i = n; i < a.length; i++) a[i] = 0;      // перекрасить хвост нулями

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));       // посмотреть что получилось
```

https://ideone.com/ErDfge

Должен заметить, что для решения Вашей проблемы "больше двух" вовсе не обязательно прибегать к такому варианту.
Их успешно можно удалять и по одному, и программа при это будет проще и понятнее.
Данный вариант служит только одной цели - попытаться минимизировать количество смещений.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int[] arg = delete(new int[]{1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,7});
        for(int i: arg) System.out.println(i);

    }

    public static int[] delete(int[] inp) {
        int out_arr[] = new int[inp.length];
        int curr = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
            if(i+1 < inp.length) {
                if(inp[i] == inp[i+1]) {
                   out_arr[curr] = inp[i];
                }else {
                    out_arr[curr+1] = inp[i+1];
                   curr++;
                }
            }
        }
        return out_arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вариант хороший, но элементы надо сместить в имеющемся массиве, без создания нового

Comment: Черт побери, опять промахнулся =)